# Using the Google Maps Android API in china

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

How to make the coordinates that located by using the Google Maps Android API (v2)  in China correctly display on google map?The type of the coordinates is WGS84 or GCJ02? Any views?

Comment: You want to create the coordinates or want to display the coordinates on a Google map?

Comment: I want to solve the offest in china when i use Google Maps Android API  to locate my current postion at my app

Answer (score 2):

At the moment Google Maps are not officially supported in China. Technically maps are working, but there are 2 major problems for your Chinese customers:

- Maps won't work without Google Play Services. Most of the Chinese users do not have them installed.
- Google Maps are actually not accurate enough and have some weird offset in coordinates.

What are your options? You will have to use Baidu maps. But the API of their library is different from Google Maps, so to solve the problem you might want to take a look at this library which we wrote: https://github.com/car2go/AnyMaps

Answer (score 1):

Google still has no map publishing license in China (at least as my latest info goes) It may well be that in the near future Google's Map services will be blocked.

A lot of Chinese websites, including ours, use Google's JS as well as their Service API's, Among them is Google's geocoding api. in china, baidu (NASDAQ:BIDU) and sogou [the minor search engine, part of sohu (NASDAQ:SOHU)] both provided online maps and also APIs,

actually, in china, as of now, the google maps api are still available now. as from recent chinatech.us news, Google China passed the annual inspection and got more opportunity to get online map business license so, the 3 API are are and available.